# How can I remove a choice from a select list with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have the following:

```
<select name="CityID" id="CityID">
  <option value="99">Select City</option>
  <option value="01H">AAA</option>
   <option value="01I">BBB</option>
</select>
```

As soon as the clicks on the select to choose an option I would like to remove the first line with option `value="99"`.

Can I do this with jQuery? I think I can do it with the `.changed()` event but are there other events that will pick up the user clicking on the select before the `.changed()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('select[name="CityID"]').focus(function() {
    $('option[value="99"]:first', this).remove();
});
```

Comment: Typo, the select name (and ID) are CityID not CityId.

Comment: There is one potential problem with this answer in that it assumes there are no other option elements on the page, with value=99, that happen to be the first elements pulled. If there is more than one select box with 2 value=99's, it's worth noting that this could be problematic.

Comment: That's not true... $('option[value="99"]:first', this), the ", this" contains the options to the select element that was focused on

Comment: Oh, you're right. I had tunnel vision on the first parameter only.  +1

Comment: @jmort253: your concerns are still valid.  If the event triggers more than once, the 2nd element will disappear.  I'm guessing that the scenario will never occur, but it probably irks you a bit too.

Comment: The only way the second value will disappear, is if its value is 99 as well

Comment: @rkw and Bryan - If it comes to that though, then the simple solution is to just put a class on the first option and uniquely separate it from all of the other option elements. I think we could go on all day with the different possible ways this could go wrong ;) As for Samantha's question, I feel like it's resolved, unless she wants to add more details or requirements, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Bryan's answer is the correct one; but here is an alternative that may not be compatible with every browser:

```
<select name="CityID" id="CityID" required>
  <option value="" disabled selected >Select City</option>
  <option value="01H">AAA</option>
   <option value="01I">BBB</option>
</select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ApeHg/2/

The `required` on the select element is html5, but it forces the user to select an element before they can submit the form (you can also re-create this behavior for older browsers)

The `disabled selected` properties on the first element tries to simulate the behavior you looking for, an un-selectable default.